# go line by line and loop?

Tags: php, text, echo

I am not good with php I'll be honest. I had a snippet of code from a while back that actually works now but it randomizes the text instead of doing line by line 1 at a time. I need it to be balanced when rotating. Here is what I have:

```
$test = file('my_txt_file.txt');
$randomized = $test[ mt_rand(0, count($test) - 1) ];
```

Then I can echo $randomized as needed throughout my page. But like I said my issue is I DO NOT want it random, but line by line in order, looping endlessly. Any thoughts on this??

Comment: When do you want the value to change? On each page load?

Answer (score 2):

Use iterators from SPL:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php

```
$test = file('my_txt_file.txt');
// this allows you to loop endlessly (vs. ArrayIterator)
$lineIterator = new InfiniteIterator($test);

// ...
// Later where you want to use the current line
echo $lineIterator->current();
$lineIterator->next(); // prepare for next call
```

This method let's you arbitrarily access the array without having an explicit list.  So you can write the echo line (or some variation) anywhere.  Should be better than a for loop from what I understand about your question.

If you don't have SPL, obviously you would have to define your own iterator class to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have SPL, you could do this:

```
$test = file('my_txt_file.txt');
$test_counter = 0;


// Whenever you want to output a line:
echo $test[$test_counter++ % count($test)];
```

Will work for over 2 billion iterations.

Comment: Good alternative to my answer!

Comment: @Matt - Would have added as comment to your answer, except that format for comments is too limited.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++){
    echo $test[$i]; //display the line
    if(($i + 1) >= count($test)) $i = -1; //makes the loop infinite
    //if you don't want it to be infinite remove the above line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$test = file('test.txt');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++) {
        echo $test[$i];
        if ($i == (count($test)-1)) {
                $i = -1;
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: nice going repeating answers :-p (im sure u ddnt mean it ^_^)